# Redux Thunk - Change state before REST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am quite new to Redux Thunk and have an issue that I want to update a contract with a 'FileList' (file appendix), but if I use JSON.stringify the file will have a 0 value. If I convert the file to Base64 this problem is solved, but the PUT request is performed before the file is converted.

I searched a lot about Redux Thunk and think it might be some issue with Dispatch, I tried quite a lot and didn't become much wiser. Most of the things that I tried returned: "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Would appreciate some help or some search suggestions..

ps. contract.answers[0].answer[0] is the file. This acquires some refactoring, but first it needs to work.

```
const toBase64 = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
});

export function updateContract(contract) {
  const base64File = toBase64(contract.answers[0].answer[0]);
  base64File.then((value) => {
    contract.answers[0].answer[0] = value; //Set file as base64
  });
  return {
    type: SAVE,
    fetchConfig: {
      uri: contract._links.self,
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(contract), // Does not handle files
      failureHandler(error) {
        const {
          details,
          status,
        } = error;

        // If the contract was invalid, throw form errors:
        if (status.code === 400 && details) {
          // Map the question ids to fields:
          throw new SubmissionError(Object.keys(details).reduce(
            (acc, questionId) => {
              acc[`question${questionId}`] = details[questionId];
              return acc;
            },
            {},
          ));
        }

        return {
          type: SAVE_FAILURE,
          error,
        };
      },
      successHandler(json) {
        return {
          type: SAVE_SUCCESS,
          data: json,
        };
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Kind regards,
Gust de Backer

Answer (score 0):

This happen because `toBase64` return a `Promise` and itself is async, so in your case is necessary encapsule inside a new `then`.

```
export function updateContract(contract) {
  const base64File = toBase64(contract.answers[0].answer[0]);
  base64File.then((value) => {
    contract.answers[0].answer[0] = value; //Set file as base64
  });
  return (dispatch) => {
    base64File.then(() => dispatch({
      type: SAVE,
      fetchConfig: {
        uri: contract._links.self,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(contract), // Does not handle files
        failureHandler(error) {
          const {
            details,
            status,
          } = error;

          // If the contract was invalid, throw form errors:
          if (status.code === 400 && details) {
            // Map the question ids to fields:
            throw new SubmissionError(Object.keys(details).reduce(
              (acc, questionId) => {
                acc[`question${questionId}`] = details[questionId];
                return acc;
              }, {},
            ));
          }

          return {
            type: SAVE_FAILURE,
            error,
          };
        },
        successHandler(json) {
          return {
            type: SAVE_SUCCESS,
            data: json,
          };
        },
      },
    }))
  };
}
```

Yes, the redux accept a function as return, that function receive a dispatch on params, you can use it to dispatch the request after convert is ready :)

Comment: Thank for you answer Fuechter, unfortunately it didn't work. My colleague helped me out, thanks for the effort!